# post request inside a loop and nested promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise

i would like to have some help!

i am trying to make a post request for each array element.

the problem is that i need to accumulate the answers from each post response and then return the count array to the calling function.
i think my basic  problem that the count returned is 0 (as initialized), in other words the post request didn't finish yet and the answer has already returned.

and i also think my code is too nested i need help to simplify pleas

thanks

```
function gt({ username, startDate, endDate }) {
  const query = '....' //never mind here 

  client.request(query, { username:arguments[0],
    startDate:arguments[1],
    endDate:arguments[2]})
      .then((response)=>{
        //response here is ok and what i expect then i want to send the response for proccesing and get the answer back in categories

        let count = getCategories(response["transactions"]);
// here is the wanted result should be in the returned answer
        console.log(count);
      })
      .catch((err)=>{console.log(err)});

}

function getCategories(transactions){

  let count = CATEGORIES; /// some json with keys and values
  Object.keys(count).forEach(v => count[v] = 0)  /// zero the values

  for (var i=0;i<transactions.length;i++){
    let transaction= transactions[i];
    axios.post(SERVER_URL, {
      transDescription: transaction["description"]
    })
        .then( function (response) {
          let category = response.data["transactionCategory"];
          console.log(category)
          count[category]+= transaction["amount"];}) //accumulating in count and then return when loop finishes
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
  }

  return count;
}
```

calling to gt function :

```
gt('some username','some date','some date'); 

// i expect to get the count variable here and print it
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, your `for` loop finishes before any of the `axios` requests complete and their promises resolve.

Also, you would probably want your `gt` function to actually return something: a promise of the count.

I would suggest using `async` and `await`, which are very practical for loops with asynchronous code.

NB: `Promise.all` is an alternative, but then you might send to many requests at almost the same time.

```
function gt({ username, startDate, endDate }) {
    const query = "...";

    return client.request(query, {
//  ^^^^^^    
        username:arguments[0],
        startDate:arguments[1],
        endDate:arguments[2]
    }).then((response) => {
        let categories = getCategories(response["transactions"]);
        console.log(categories);
        return categories; // <----
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
}

async function getCategories(transactions) {
//^^^
    let count = CATEGORIES;
    Object.keys(count).forEach(v => count[v] = 0);

    for (var i = 0; i < transactions.length; i++) {
        let transaction = transactions[i];
        let response = await axios.post(SERVER_URL, {
//      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            transDescription: transaction["description"]
        });
        let category = response.data["transactionCategory"];
        console.log(category)
        count[category] += transaction["amount"];
    }
    return count;
}
```

Another comment is needed on `CATEGORIES`: your code mutates that object structure. This can be "dangerous" if you call this function a second time and `CATEGORIES` is used again: in that scenario the previous results are overwritten. It would be more prudent to actually take a copy each time you initialise `count`:

```
let count = {...CATEGORIES};
```

Comment: thank you first!well i am not sure i understood the reason for  "response" in getCategories function.
i tried to add your changes but nothing changed i'll try to edit again for more information

Comment: and i would like to see how to do it with promise.all please :)
@trincot

Comment: I did not change anything concerning `response` in `getCategories`. You already had a reference to it, right? When you say "nothing changed"... could you be more specific. This code cannot behave the same as you had, since here we have `async` / `await`.